# How to parenthesize a word in a Ruby string

Tags: ruby

I have this string `"Unit Number"`. I want to change it to `"Unit (Number)"`.

How would I insert the parentheses for just the 2nd word?, the length of each words and actual words will be different for each string.

For example, it could be `"Animal Name"`, and it would need to look like `"Animal (Name)"`.

I've been playing around with different methods and I'm nowhere close to a solution.

Comment: You should demonstrate the code that you wrote to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting and using map to store the elements checking for the last one to parenthesize would be a way:

```
def parenthesize_last_word(string)
  str = string.split
  str.map { |word| word == str.last ? "(#{word})" : word }.join(' ')
end

p parenthesize_last_word 'Unit Number' # "Unit (Number)"
p parenthesize_last_word 'Animal Name' # "Animal (Name)"
```

Or using sub:

```
p 'Unit Number'.sub(/(\w+)$/, '(\1)') # "Unit (Number)"
p 'Animal Name'.sub(/(\w+)$/, '(\1)') # "Animal (Name)"
```

Comment: Or `"(\\1)"` if you use double quotes for the substitution string.

Comment: I prefer the `.sub` solutions, since it might be desirable to preserve the word separators which could be one or more occurrences of any kind of non-word characters.

Comment: I guess first approach was a fail of mine, actual version seems to be faster than the one using sub. But yes, I prefer the one using sub. As per the `"(\\1)"`, I think as there's nothing to interpolate I chose simple quotes.

Comment: Since I sometimes am running one-liners with `ruby -e`, where you need to quote the command to be executed, I like to have flexibility to use either kind of quote depending on the broader context.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Ruby String #sub](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/sub)

```
"Unit Number".sub(/(\w+)$/, '(\1)') -> "Unit (Number)"
"Animal Name".sub(/(\w+)$/, '(\1)') -> "Animal (Name)"
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because `$1` lags in getting updated, so `ruby -e 'p "Unit Number".sub(/Number/, "(#{$1})")'` => `"Unit ()"`.  It also is hardwired to "Number" as the second word, so it doesn't meet the requirements after OP's edit.